# Get the monday of the last complete week within a month in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not all months have a complete set of days in it's last week. I'll be needing this to send a reminder to track hours for the remaining days on the last week of the month, but the week should be complete set. Please help me.

Comment: Are you thinking of the working week being Monday-Friday? So if the last day of the month is a Friday, that would be a full week? Ideally put in one or two examples and say what you're tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumption above is correct and you have a date in the required month in A2 (e.g.1/3/16), this should do it:-

```
=EOMONTH(A2,0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A2,0),15)-3
```

This gives today (21/3/16) as the Monday of the last complete week in March 2016, which would be correct.

Comment: I changed A2 to Today() and this worked fine. :D Thank you for this!

Comment: Glad it worked. Of course I'm conveniently ignoring the fact that this Friday is a public holiday in a lot of countries - there are always going to be complications around Christmas, Easter and other public holidays that this formula doesn't attempt to address.